# WGET doesn't work with plunder.com

Tags: bash, ssh, centos, wget, vps

Few days ago I purchased VPS with CentOS 6 and now I need to download some files from plunder.com using WGET command via SSH but I always get error:

```
-bash: !: event not found
```

Please help me!

Comment: What is the url you're trying to download?

Comment: Please show the line that throws the error

Comment: Enclose URL in single quotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message

```
-bash: !: event not found
```

suggests that there is an exclamation point in your command; and the shell is trying to expand it before passing it to `wget`.

Usually a backslash in front of exclamation points will fix this.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$ curl -0 <url you're downloading> -o <name you want to save the file as>
```

Type

```
$ man curl
```

to make sure you have curl and for more information about the command